# Why my code is not displaying in a react return?

Tags: reactjs

I have created basic home page with search option, but unfortunatelly ,,There aren't any hotels h2 tag is not displaying. I am rendering a list of hotels adding them on the firebase and i have delete option as well. Upon deleting all of the hotels from the list I was hoping to see a message that there aren't any hotels, but surprisingly it's not displaying. Any idea why?

```
function Card() {
  const [hotels, setHotels] = useState<NewHotelType[]>([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")

  useEffect(
    () =>
      onSnapshot(hotelsCollection, (snapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
        setHotels(
          snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            return {
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            };
          })
        );
      }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="search">
        <input className="inputsearch" 
        value={search} type="text" placeholder="Search for the hotel" onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)}
        />
    </div>
    {!!hotels? (
      <div>
    {hotels?.filter((item:NewHotelType) => {
          if (search === "" && !search.length) {
            return item;
          }
          return item?.title === search;
        })
        ?.map((hotel:NewHotelType) => (<Information key={hotel.id} hotel={hotel}
        /> 
        )
        )}
        </div>
    ) : (
      <h2 className="no-hotels">There are no hotels. Please add one</h2>
    )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

Array types do not have the "duck-type" functionality you're trying to use.

```js
const arr = []
console.log(!!arr) // -> true
```

What you'll want to do is either `setHotels` to `null` as initial state and when there are none returned, and do a "duck-type" check in your return

```js
{hotels ? {hotels.filter()} : <h2>No hotels</h2>
```

OR keep the same data structures and check for an array length:

```js
{hotels.length ? {hotels.filter()} : <h2>No hotels</h2>
```

**EDIT**

If no results are returned from your filter, I assume you'll also want to display the fallback h2.  In that case do a check on the filtered hotels in your condition:

```js
{hotels.filter().length ? {hotels.filter().map()} : <h2>No hotels</h2>}
```